# Delphi xe10.2 open new Ms word document and insert table

Tags: delphi, ms-word

in delphi xe 10.2 what is the correct format for following code
MSWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment :=wdAlignParagraphJustify;

Comment: The title and body text have very little do with each other. Also, the "format" is OK if you only add a space after ":=".

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more on your question? It is hard to understand what exactly you want here. Just EDIT your question, and try to avoid posting comments on your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code illustrates a way of creating a new Word document, inserting
a table into it, and then specifying the alignment of the cells.

Notice that it has two calls to `MSWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphJustify`,
one immediately after the table is created, and another one inside the `for` loop which sets up the table's
cells.  This is to illustrate a potential problem with using `MSWord.Selection`, namely that the `Selection`
may not be what you expect, and so operating on it can produce unexpected/undesired results.

If you comment out the second call to `MSWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphJustify`
you will notice that only the first cell gets that alignment. and after that the the alignment of the
remaining cells reverts to what it was prior to the creating of the table.  If you comment out the first
call instead, you'll find that in terms of the alignment of the cells, it is superflous.

```
procedure TForm1.CreateTable(Rows, Columns : Integer);
var
  MSWord,
  Document,
  Table,
  Range,
  Cell: OleVariant;
  ARow,
  AColumn: Integer;
  RowIndex,
  ColIndex : Integer;
  S : String;
begin
  MsWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  MsWord.Visible := True;

  Document := MSWord.Documents.Add;
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Size := 22;
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Bold := true;
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(#13#10);
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText('This should be center-aligned');
  MSWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphCenter;
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(#13#10#13#10);
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Size := 12;
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Bold := False;

  Table := MSWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add( Range:= MSWord.Selection.Range, NumRows:= Rows, NumColumns:= Columns, DefaultTableBehavior:= wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= wdAutoFitFixed);

  MSWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphJustify;
  for ARow := 1 to Rows do begin
    for AColumn := 1 to Columns do begin
      Cell := Table.Cell(ARow, AColumn);
      RowIndex := Cell.RowIndex;
      ColIndex := Cell.ColumnIndex;
      Caption := IntToStr(RowIndex) + '/' + IntToStr(ColIndex);
      Range := Cell.Range;
      Range.Select;
      MSWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphJustify;
      if Odd(AColumn) then
        Range.Font.Bold := True
      else
        Range.Font.Bold := False;
      S := Format('Row: %d, col: %d', [RowIndex, ColIndex]);
      MSWord.Selection.Range := Range;
      MSWord.Selection.TypeText(Text := S);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for the support I am getting error message - undeclared identifier-wdAlignParagraphJustify, wdAlignParagraphCenter , wdWord9TableBehavior ,wdAutoFitFixed

Comment: Delphi comes with a .Pas file which is an import of the MS Word Type Library and this includes declarations of various constants like `wdAlignParagraphJustify`.  The file's name depends on your Delphi version.  Look for it in the Servers subfolder under the OCX folder of your Delphi set up.  Once you've found it, add it to the Uses list of your code unit.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Well, if this has helped, please feel free to accept my answer by clicking the "Tick" icon at its top left side.

Comment: Answer is very much useful. How I add a paragraph after the  table in word , the lines coming inside the table cell, how I exit out of the table and add new lines in the word document

Comment: I could tell you that, but I think it would be far more useful is I explain how I would work it out if I didn't already know the answer.  In Word, I would turn on the macro recorder, make the mouse or cursor movements necessary to move the insertion point beyond the table, then stop recording and look at what the macro contains.  It is usually fairly trivial to see what should be the equivalent Delphi code.  The advantage of learning to do this yourself is that you can then answer pretty much any "How do I ..." q yourself.